# Convert unicode code point to literal character in Go

Tags: unicode, go

Let's say I have a text file like this.

```
\u0053
\u0075
\u006E
```

Is there a way I can convert that to this?

```
S
u
n
```

Currently, I'm using `ioutil.ReadFile("data.txt")`, but when I print the data, I get the unicode code points instead of the string literals. I realize this is the correct behavior for `ReadFile`, it's just not want I want.

I'm aiming for a substitution of the code points with their literal characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) and [`strconv.UnquoteChar()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#UnquoteChar) functions to do the conversion.

One thing you should be aware of is that `strconv.Unquote()` can only unquote strings that are in quotes (e.g. start and end with a quote char `"` or a back quote char `` ` ``),  so we have to manually append that.

See this example:

```
lines := []string{
    `\u0053`,
    `\u0075`,
    `\u006E`,
}
fmt.Println(lines)

for i, v := range lines {
    var err error
    lines[i], err = strconv.Unquote(`"` + v + `"`)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
fmt.Println(lines)

fmt.Println(strconv.Unquote(`"Go\u0070\x68\x65\x72"`))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/BZO5J0233H)):

```
[\u0053 \u0075 \u006E]
[S u n]
Gopher <nil>
```

If the strings you want to unquote contain the escape sequence of a single `rune` (or you just want to unquote the first `rune`), you may use `strconv.UnquoteChar()`. This is how it looks like (note: no quoting of the input is needed in this case, like it was needed for `strconv.Unquote()`):

```
runes := []string{
    `\u0053`,
    `\u0075`,
    `\u006E`,
}
fmt.Println(runes)

for _, v := range runes {
    var err error
    value, _, _, err := strconv.UnquoteChar(v, 0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%c\n", value)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aFv7BPnVphU)):

```
[\u0053 \u0075 \u006E]
S
u
n
```

Comment: How handle the string like this "\u0070\x68\x65\x72" which already in quote. I my test, it can't.

Comment: @user3875388 If it already contains quotes, simply don't add quotes. See working example on https://play.golang.org/p/Q3WIPOkmjaB

Comment: UnquoteChar accepts a zero value rune, so you don't need to quote first. Please have a look at the Go source.

Comment: @TheDiveO Yes, that's right. I was only referring to and gave example of `strconv.Unquote()`. Added example using `strconv.UnquoteChar()` too.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different approach is using [`strconv.ParseInt`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt), this generates less garbage and uses less internal logic ([`Unquote`](https://golang.org/src/strconv/quote.go?s=7947:7991#L296) does a lot of other checks) for parsing the lines:

```
for i, v := range lines {
    if len(v) != 6 {
        continue
    }

    if r, err := strconv.ParseInt(v[2:], 16, 32); err == nil {
        lines[i] = string(r)
    }
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/MrVgUN_p7Y)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```golang
import "github.com/chzyer/readline/runes"

// unicodeUnquote converts unicode points such as \u0053 to UTF8 encoding.
func unicodeUnquote(bs []byte) []byte {
    unicodeEscapeRx := regexp.MustCompile(`\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}`)
    return unicodeEscapeRx.ReplaceAllFunc(bs, func(code []byte) []byte {
        rune, _, _, _ := strconv.UnquoteChar(string(code), 0)
        width := runes.Width(rune)
        runeBytes := make([]byte, width)
        utf8.EncodeRune(runeBytes, rune)
        return runeBytes
    })
}
```

A full example is at https://go.dev/play/p/ElIGZvJNyEF.