# unicode being output literally instead of as unicode

Tags: go, irc

I am creating an IRC bot using Go as a first project to get to grips with the language.  One of the bot functions is to grab data from the TVmaze API and display in the channel.

I have imported an env package which allows the bot admin to define how the output is displayed.

For example `SHOWSTRING="#showname# - #status# – #network.name#"`

I am trying to add functionality to it so that the admin can use IRC formatting functionality which is accessed with `\u0002 this is bold \u0002` for example.

I have a function which generates the string that is being returned and displayed in the channel.

```
func generateString(show Show) string {
  str := os.Getenv("SHOWSTRING")
  r := strings.NewReplacer(
    "#ID#", string(show.ID),
    "#showname#", show.Name,
    "#status#", show.Status,
    "#network.name#", show.Network.Name,
  )
  result := r.Replace(str)
  return result
}
```

From what i have read i think that i need to use the `rune` datatype instead of string and then converting the runes into a string before being output.

I am using the https://github.com/thoj/go-irceven package for interacting with IRC.

Although i think that using `rune` is the correct way to go, i have tried a few things that have confused me.

If i add `\u0002` to the SHOWSTRING from the env, it returns `\u0002House\u0002 - Ended - Fox`. I am doing this by `con.Privmsg(roomName, tvmaze.ShowLookup('house'))`

However if i try `con.Privmsg(roomName, "\u0002This should be bold\u0002")` it outputs bold text.

What is the best option here? If it is converting the string into runes and then back to a string, how do i go about doing that?

Comment: You need to unquote the input.  The function https://godoc.org/strconv#Unquote might be helpful.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Convert unicode code point to literal character in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126749/convert-unicode-code-point-to-literal-character-in-go)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use `strconv.Unquote()` on my return in the function.

The new generateString function now outputs the correct string and looks like this

```
func generateString(show Show) string {
  str := os.Getenv("SHOWSTRING")
  r := strings.NewReplacer(
    "#ID#", string(show.ID),
    "#showname#", show.Name,
    "#status#", show.Status,
    "#network.name#", show.Network.Name,
  )
  result := r.Replace(str)
  ret, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + result + `"`)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error unquoting the string")
  }
  return ret
}
```