# How to unescape quoted octal strings in Golang?

Tags: string, go, escaping

I have the following string:

```
`\303\250\303\252\303\256\303\264\303\247`
```

I need to convert it to

```
"èêîôç"
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert unicode code point to literal character in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126749/convert-unicode-code-point-to-literal-character-in-go/34127730#34127730); and [How to convert escape characters in HTML tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36528575/how-to-convert-escape-characters-in-html-tags/36529158#36529158)

Comment: Not a duplicate IMO.  This is about Octal, those are about Unicode.  The two are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I got it

```
 a := `"\303\250\303\252\303\256\303\264\303\247"`
 b, err := strconv.Unquote(a)
```