# How to read "\t" as tab in golang

Tags: string, go, command-line, command-line-arguments

I tried to parse `"\t"` from shell as `TAB`, however, it does not work.

Here I give a simple example.

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var sep string
    flag.StringVar(&sep, "sep", " ", "separator")
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Println("name" + sep + "xxx")

    // separator is quoted by golang
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", sep)
}
```

The result:

```
$ go run main.go -sep '\t'
name\txxx
"\\t"
```

Is there an easy solution?

Comment: This looks correct to me. Doing `fmt.Println("Hello \t world")` will be a tab within text. How your output-console interprets this is a different question.

Comment: In bash and zsh (at least): `go run main.go -sep $'\t'`. This makes the shell interpret `\t` and passes the single byte 0x09 to go. No special code required.

Comment: @C4d Thanks. I know it is correct, I care how to output TAB by controlling input.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, this indeed works for shell including `git bash`.

Comment: @ShixiangWang Oh I just realized the problem in here. It gets escaped and printed. Sorry, misunderstood it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\t` is a backslash escape which denotes the tab character (e.g. in interpreted string literals). If you have the backslash escape, you may use [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) to "decode" it (into the tab character).

One thing you must know: `strconv.Unquote()` requires its argument to be in quotes, e.g. you have to pass `"\t"` not simply `\t`.

```
sep, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + sep + `"`)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

With this addition, running `go run main.go -sep '\t'`, the output is:

```
name    xxx
"\t"
```

See related questions:

[How to transform Go string literal code to its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303559/how-to-transform-go-string-literal-code-to-its-value/49304209#49304209)

[Convert unicode code point to literal character in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126749/convert-unicode-code-point-to-literal-character-in-go/34127730#34127730)